# Angular 6 progress bar service

Tags: angular, progress-bar, angular6

Am trying to build a progress service to know that is the total and the percentage loaded of files. i wrote the service below and register it in the provider section;

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx'
import { BrowserXhr } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class ProgressService {
  uploadProgress = new Subject<any>();
  downloadProgress = new Subject<any>();

}


@Injectable()
export class BrowserXhrWithProgress extends BrowserXhr {

  constructor(private service: ProgressService) {
    super();
  }
  build(): XMLHttpRequest {
    var xhr: XMLHttpRequest = super.build();
    xhr.onprogress = (event) => {
      this.service.downloadProgress.next(this.createProgress(event));
    };

    xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
      this.service.uploadProgress.next(this.createProgress(event));
    };
    return xhr;
  }

  private createProgress(event: any) {
    return {
      total: event.total,
      percentage: Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100)
    };
  }
}
```

an I subscribe to the service as bellow before loading the file;

```
this.progressService.uploadProgress.subscribe(progress => { console.log(progress) });
```

but am not able to log any thing in console.

```
  { provide: BrowserXhr, useClass: BrowserXhrWithProgress },
   ProgressService
```

any idea well be helpful.

Comment: Did you check this... you can listen to progress events with the httpclient: https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events

Comment: @AJT_82 you say not to use BrowserXhr. this might be more interesting